# Переписать код из с++11 в с++03.

Tags: boost, c++11, c++, linux

Здравствуйте, помогите переписать код из с++11 стандарта под С++03 стандарт.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

using namespace std;

class directory_range
{
    directory_range(bfs_dir_iter itr): _itr(itr)
    bfs_dir_iter _itr;

public:
    directory_range(bfs_dir_iter&& itr): _itr(itr)
    {
    }

    bfs_dir_iter begin()
    {
        return _itr;
    }

    bfs_dir_iter end()
    {
        return bfs_dir_iter();
    }
};

int main()
{
    namespace bfs = boost::filesystem3;

    bfs::path p("/home/root/test/");
    if(!bfs::is_directory(p))
    {
        std::cerr << "[ ERROR ] ";
        std::cerr << p << " isn't directory. Stopping...." << std::endl;
        return ENOENT;
    }

    const char** dirs_begin = dirs;
    const char* dirs[] = {"part1", "part2", "part3", "part4", "part5"};

     BOOST_FOREACH(const char* dir, dirs)
        try
        {
            bfs::create_directory(p / dir);
        }
        catch(const bfs::filesystem_error& e)
        {
                std::cerr   << "[ ERROR ] ";
                std::cerr   << (p / dir).filename()
                            << " is already exists and not directory. "
                            << "Stopping..." << std::endl;
                return ENOENT;
        }

  const char** dirs_iter = dirs;
     BOOST_FOREACH (const bfs::directory_entry& file,
             std::make_pair(bfs::directory_iterator(p), bfs::directory_iterator()))     
        {
        if(!bfs::is_regular_file(file))
        {
            std::cerr   << "[WARNING] ";
            std::cerr   << file.path().filename() << " isn't regular file. "
                        << "Go to the hell, I will not copy it." << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if(bfs::exists(p / *dirs_iter / file.path().filename()))
            {
                std::cerr   << "[WARNING] ";
                std::cerr   << file.path().filename()
                            << " is already exists in " << *dirs_iter
                            << ". Skipping..." << std::endl;
                continue;
            }

            bfs::copy(file, p / *dirs_iter++ / file.path().filename());
                if(dirs_iter == dirs_end)
                 dirs_iter = dirs_begin;

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А в чем проблемы? Убираете все rvalue references, auto и range-based for - и все работает.

Comment: Вы тут насоветуете. Не просто убрать, а переписать в рамках стандарта С++2003

Comment: Да именно переписать нужно...

Comment: @karr, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу. Напишите, что непонятно.

Comment: А пардон, ну непонятно конкретно что нужно убрать, добавить, поменять, чтобы код отвечал стандарту C++2003, я с этими стандартами и не заморачивался-то никогда...

Comment: Русское сообщество слишком доброе

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как-то так. for (:) меняем на BOOST_FOREACH и везде явно указываем типы, вместо auto:

```
6a7
> #include <boost/foreach.hpp>
14c15
<     directory_range(bfs_dir_iter&& itr): _itr(itr)
---
>     directory_range(bfs_dir_iter itr): _itr(itr)
41a43,44
>     const char** dirs_begin = dirs;
>     const char** dirs_end = dirs + sizeof(dirs) / sizeof(const char*);
43c46
<     for(const auto& dir: dirs)
---
>     BOOST_FOREACH(const char* dir, dirs)
57,58c60,63
<     auto dirs_iter = std::begin(dirs);
<     for(const auto& file: directory_range(bfs::directory_iterator(p)))
---
>     const char** dirs_iter = dirs;
>     BOOST_FOREACH (const bfs::directory_entry& file,
>             std::make_pair(bfs::directory_iterator(p),
>                            bfs::directory_iterator()))
78,79c83,84
<             if(dirs_iter == std::end(dirs))
<                 dirs_iter = std::begin(dirs);
---
>             if(dirs_iter == dirs_end)
>                 dirs_iter = dirs_begin;
```

Comment: Начал заменять, получилась каша полная какая-то...В конце-концов не скомпилилось, как я и предпологал...

Comment: @karr, пишите на минимальной версии (а лучше на чистом Си) и на четко выделенных системных вызовах.

Проблемы переноса минимизируются.

Comment: Телепаты в отпуске.

Comment: В топике поменял код, с заменой строчек указанных вами. Может я где-то что-то не удалил или не добавил?

Comment: @karr Вам же дали патч, как можно что-то не удалить / не добавить?

Comment: @karr, комментарий к тому что эти изменения надо было не вносить руками, а применить с помощью утилиты patch. Расшарил исправленный файл http://pastie.org/4466091.

Comment: Премного извиняюсь, все работает. Спасибо.

Comment: Тогда отметьте ответ на вопрос как отмеченный (принятый)